# Approval Process Status in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, approval-process

Is it possible to pull the Status field of an approval process into a Visualforce page that is only using a standard controller for a custom object?  I tried using `{!Custom_Object__c.ProcessInstance.Status}` but that does not work.

Comment: Can you try {!Custom_Object__r.ProcessInstance.Status}? The __r showing the traversal of the related object.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  Unfortunately, no.  I get the error "Unknown property 'Custom_Object__cStandardController.Custom_Object__r'

Answer (score 1):

ProcessInstance staus can not be accessed directly from the object.
You can query it in the constructor of the extension:

```
SELECT status FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId=:(Custom_Object__c)controller.getRecord().id;
```

Comment: Thanks.  As I mentioned, I'm not using a custom controller though and was trying to avoid doing so.